# no me cargan los datos en mi segunda factura

Tags: php, mysql

Verán tengo una factura en `php`, la cual le duplico el código y todo funciona bien, excepto por el hecho de que no me carga la consulta de los productos cantidades etc. aquí el ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

como pueden ver no me carga y es este pedazo del codigo:

```
<?php

                if($result_detalle > 0){

                    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_productos)){
             ?>
                <tr>
                    <td class="textcenter"><?php echo $row['cantidad']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['descripcion']; ?></td>
                    <td class="textleft"><?php echo $row['precio']; ?></td>
                    <td>     _____________</td>
                    <td class="textright">$________________</td>
                </tr>
            <?php
                        $precio_total = 0;
                        $subtotal = ($subtotal + $precio_total);
                    }
                }

                
                $tl_sniva   = ($subtotal );
                $total      = ($tl_sniva );
            ?>
```

Alguien sabe porque, la primera factura si pero la segunda no.

Comment: Y esos datos están bien en la base de datos? La query funciona si la pones directamente en el gestor?

Comment: cual es el valor de `$result_detalle` exactamente antes del if??

Comment: si bro funciona bien, de hecho la primer factura funciona correctamente, y el valor de result detalle es un query

Comment: no entiendo; creo que debes hacer debug y evaluar que tiene la variable $result_detalle y ponerlo en tu post, aparte de eso no estas evaluando si $query_productos tiene algun retorno de datos ... y otra cosa no entiendo por que evaluar una variables y despues iteras la otra ... es como que falta mas explicacion a lo que intentas hacer ...

Comment: Después de que extraes el resultado de una consulta con `while`, el puntero queda en la última fila por lo cual cuando quieres hacerlo de nuevo es como si no hubiera información, para esto debes agregar `mysqli_data_seek($result_detalle, 0);` para regresar el puntero a la posición inicial

Comment: uffff esta genial amigo pero te pregunto, el mysqli_data_seek($result_detalle, 0); se reemplaza por el que tiene el while?, podrias regalare un ejemplo de como podria usarlo yo tenia la sospecha de que en la consulta while podria pasar algo por el estilo, pero no estaba seguro

Comment: arcanis, sino que debo verificar que $result_detalle si lleve los datos de la consulta para con el while poder cargarlos y buscarlos, si o si necesito que $result_detalle no vaya vacio por eso el if, lo que me dijo MR Dev era lo que sospechaba pero no se como implementar lo que me dice francamente